# Statically compile Postgresql on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, build

How can I statically compile Postgres from source on Ubuntu 12.04?

I've installed the necessary dev dependencies, including `libreadline-dev`, `zlib1g-dev`, and `libssl-dev`, and can successfully build normally, but fail when attempting to compile statically.

The failing command:

```
./configure --prefix=/build/dir --with-openssl LDFLAGS=-static && make && make install
```

The configure script runs successfully, but `make` fails with the following output:

> hba.c:(.text+0xa7): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `memcmp' with pointer equality in`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(memcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie

Comment: Why would you want to compile it statically?

Comment: I'm trying to build the binary on one machine, and copy it to a similar machine without a compiler or network access.