# Is it possible to build PostgreSQL for multiple linux versions/distros at once?

Tags: linux, postgresql, makefile

I used to get the PostgreSQL binaries from EDB for Linux but after 11 it no longer has them (from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries).

Because before this used to be possible and the download is independant of the Linux distro and version, I'm guessing there must be way.

Currently, I'm building PostgreSQL in Ubunutu 22.04 and then trying to use it on Ubuntu 20.04 as well as RHEL 7.9 and it won't work. I usually get missing .so files but now after inlcuding openssl I also get stuff like:

```
./initdb: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./initdb)
```

I got around the issues with the .so files by including them in the lib directory and then adding them as symlinks to the system lib folder but this one I can't seem to get around.

So my question is: Is there a way that I can reliably build PostgreSQL in a way that it is compatible with various versions and distributions of Linux such as Ubuntu 20, 22, RHEL, CentOS, etc?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to add that this is meant to be included on an offline installer so that is why I'm doing this as I can't rely on native repositories like apt or yum.

Comment: You can often avoid the `version 'GLIBC_2.33' not found` problem by building on the *older* distribution, rather than the newer one. The binary will generally run successfully on both the older and newer releases.

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know, I was not aware of it. I will try that!

Comment: If you build from source and statically link everything into your distribution, the executable won't rely on system libraries.  It will also be a lot bigger because it will contain all those system libraries.  But it will run on any linux machine of the same architecture

Comment: @erik258 You cannot link PostgreSQL statically.

Comment: Looking around SO I found this: [LDFLAGS='--static'](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAORuWe0P5%3D1AqVWzWU0wq6ddUQSEfrJorOzPbKrgFO1qQeP6SA%40mail.gmail.com) and this: [LDFLAGS=-static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938139/statically-compile-postgresql-on-ubuntu)
So are these not viable?

Comment: Well, maybe not super easily at least https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10384.1639260044%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build it on the OLDEST system you want to run on.  Libraries like the C runtime library (`libc`) are backward-compatible (that is, newer versions work with code that was compiled against an older version) but they are not forward-compatible (that is, older versions won't work with code that was compiled against a newer version).

If you don't want to do that, you'll need to create a new sysroot containing the oldest libraries you want to run with and configure your compiler to use that, instead of the standard libraries on the system.  This is not simple but it's not rocket science.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! The sysroot option also seems interesting but since I already run multiple VMs with the different version I'll definitely give it a go on the first option.

Comment: So I finally got hands on an older version but now I'm getting this when compiling PostgreSQL: 
`/usr/bin/ld: libpq/be-secure-openssl.o: in function 'be_tls_open_server':`
`be-secure-openssl.c:(.text+0x19b0): undefined reference to 'ERR_new'`
(...)
`/usr/bin/ld: be-secure-openssl.c:(.text+0x19db): undefined reference to 'ERR_set_error'`
`/usr/bin/ld: be-secure-openssl.c:(.text+0x1a41): undefined reference to 'ERR_new'`
`/usr/bin/ld: be-secure-openssl.c:(.text+0x1a61): undefined reference to 'SSL_get1_peer_certificate'`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Any idea why?

Comment: It seems that the OpenSSL library on that older system is too old, or else PostgreSQL needs to be configured differently.  I can't say you'll have to investigate the requirements for building PostgreSQL (maybe there's a README or INSTALL file or something).  If you can't work it out you may have to also build your own version of OpenSSL from source on this older system.

Comment: I was thinking it was "too new" if that's a thing. Because I did build OpenSSL myself, tried with versions 3.1 and 3.0 as well but no dice.
This was on Ubuntu 20.04. As it only has the 1.1 version of OpenSSL that's why I manually built it. It is likely that I may have missed some files when removing the old one.

Comment: You absolutely need the 1.1 version.  OpenSSL 3.x is a completely new API and is not fully compatible with the older API (a bunch of stuff is deprecated).  Only systems which have been reworked to support the new API, can be used with OpenSSL 3.x.

Comment: I was going for the latest ones because 1.1 is EOL at the moment and I did try to build PostgreSQL (14.6) with 1.1 but was unsuccessful however with 3.0 I was able to do it.
(This was on a previous test with a more recent version of RHEL)
This complicates things a bit. Anyway, thanks for the insight, seems like this one will be a big head scratcher.

Comment: I find it unlikely that PostgeSQL 14 dropped support for OpenSSL 1.1.1 since that's what most GNU/Linux systems still use.  However you should be able to find all the info about prerequisites etc. in the build docs for Postgres: maybe there's some option you need to set or something.  Usually systems self-configure for things like that but who knows.  OpenSSL 1.1.1 is not EOL; it's still supported until September at least.

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay in the follow-up, other high-priority stuff came along.
I finally got it working with compiling on an older version, but I do still need to compile per distro, thanks everyone for the guidance, learned a lot with this troubleshooting.